# Session logout while fetch lots of data

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I store a site login values in a temporary session using:

`$mysession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('mysession');`

& i when i am trying to fetch data over 1 lakhs records it automatically clearing all sessions & redirects to login page

I have tried different solutions like above for increase execution limit

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '8000M');
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 14400);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 14400);
```

I am using mysql query to fetch data.

So any suggestions

Comment: I thought issue in time limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set expiration time for :

```
$mysession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('mysession');
$namespace->setExpirationSeconds(999);
```

//or

```
$namespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');
$namespace->setExpirationSeconds(999);
```

Answer (score 3):

If fetching data takes **THAT** long, that the session expires in between, consider restructuring your application instead of setting crucial limitations up to unlimited / infinite.

Imagine, your session will not expire, what next? Do you want to send this bulk of 100,000 records to the client and crash that?

Second, if the five minutes and the 8Gig will be utilized and you have 10 clients, your machine need 80 Gig min. on Memory to handle that? How likely is it, to have ten clients within five minutes starting this php thread?

And, if you set up your database properly, `SELECT`-ing 100,000 records usually takes only seconds?